# is it possible to package a 'real' mongodb library for use on the *server* side only in meteor 0.6

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I understand that the 'mini-mongo' packaged with meteor up till 0.6 had a few limitations around aggregation, but hoping the story is a bit easier with the release of 0.6.

What I'm trying to work around is the lack of 'aggregation' in mini-mongo.

I have a mongodb with records like this

```
db.account_records.findOne()
{
    "type" : "initial_balance",
    "amt" : 10,
    "account_id" : "95CPB9Be8NX3TGSpi",
    "_id" : "L9D7Agt4gW2Ht4NTA"
}
```

and I want to subscribe (at client) to a query like the following..

```
db.events.aggregate( [ { $group: {_id:"$account_id", balance: { $sum: "$amt"}}}]);
```

.. which gives (when run using "real" mongodb from terminal "mongo meteor" style)..

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "Dn5Eouw8K4RrP9SGw",
            "balance" : 169.99922000000308
        },
        {
            "_id" : "Bawopno2QGs8guMWy",
            "balance" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : "95CPB9Be8NX3TGSpi",
            "balance" : 5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

It seems unlikely to me that it will ever be possible (or desirable) to perform complex aggregate clauses client side so i can see the reason we have mini-mongo. But I was hoping that with the ability to install standard npm modules in the new version of meteor it might be a bit easier to create a query that I can publish from 'real' mongo and subscribe to in mini-mongo?

--

PS I found this already but all those double underscores are making me nervous I'd be attempting something complicated...
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that aggregation push on your server as used. Prior to the Meteor 0.6.0 'engine' version `npm` module integration was still very unofficial hence the underscores, finally it can be used officially so below should work (from that github pull modified to work on 0.6.0 : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/644)

**Server side js**

```
var path = Npm.require('path');
var MongoDB = Npm.require('mongodb');
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

var Animals = new Meteor.Collection("animals");

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Animals.aggregate = function(pipeline) {
    var self = this;

    var future = new Future;
    self.find()._mongo.db.createCollection(self._name, function (err, collection) {
      if (err) {
        future.throw(err);
        return;
      }
      collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          future.throw(err);
          return;
        }
        future.ret([true, result]);
      });
    });
    var result = future.wait();
    if (!result[0])
      throw result[1];

    return result[1];
  };

});

Meteor.methods({
  myAggregationMethod: function() {
    return Animals.aggregate([ {$project: {dog:1, age:1}}, {$sort:{age:1}} ]);
  }
});
```

And on your **client js**, when you want to call an aggregation:

```
    Meteor.call('myAggregationMethod', function(err,result) {
      if (!err) {
          console.log(result)          
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

**Adding the mongodb package**

1) Make a directory in your project called packages to store your packages & in that another directory called mongodb for the mongodb npm package

2) Add a file in mongodb called `package.js` containing

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Mongodb driver"
});

Npm.depends({'mongodb':"1.2.14"});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('lib.js', 'server');
});
```

Add another file in the same mongodb directory called `lib.js` containing:

```
if(typeof(Npm) != "undefined") {
    MongoDB = Npm.require("mongodb");
}
else
{
    console.log("Please upgrade meteor to 0.6.0")
    MongoDB = __meteor_bootstrap__.require("mongodb");
}
```

Finally remove the line

`var MongoDB = Npm.require("mongodb")` from your `server.js` as we globally scoped it in `lib.js`

Comment: Thanks for this Akshat I've voted up your answer and will accept it soon if nobody else responds. However - as explained in my own answer on this thread I am unable to actually get this solution to work. So until then I can't really say whether it works or not.

Comment: Akshat, I accepted your answer and thanks for this. I've ended up with something very similar to what you proposed, whcih you can see here https://github.com/utunga/pocketmeteor/tree/master/packages/mongowrapper. Thanks also to @avital for all your help on IRC.

EDIT when I get a chance I'll probably switch to doing the typeof(NPM) thing also.

Comment: Actually your package make the solution better, one of the reasons npm is added differently than to the typical `x= require(..)` is that with npm packages fibers support can be added in without cluttering up server side js code. With your package you can directly call aggregation without having a cluttered up non fibers code in the server.js file

Answer (score 1):

to fix Akshat's answer for Meteor 0.9.0, use this:

```
self.find()._mongo._withDb(function(db) {
  return db.createCollection(self._name, function(err, collection) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      future.throw(err);
      return;
    }
    return collection.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        future.throw(err);
        return;
      }
      return future["return"]([true, result]);
    });
  });
});
```

Also, no need to include `MongoDB = Npm.require("mongodb")` in the header.